# How to make web_sync and poll ResponseCB() NOT as wasted time in Loadrunner?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

For an async `web_url` Loadrunner has added the `web_reg_async_attributes`. Within the `Poll_0_ResponseCB` I'm waiting until the `aHttpStatusCode == 200`. This is needed because it's an XHR request where the server transfers all the data async to the browser. The transaction is considered finished AFTER all the data has been received in the GET request.

The request looks as following:

```
        web_reg_async_attributes("ID=Poll_0", 
            "Pattern=Poll", 
            "URL=https://[URL]/api2/notifications/GetUnreadNotifications", 
            "PollIntervalMs=500", 
            "RequestCB=Poll_0_RequestCB", 
            "ResponseCB=Poll_0_ResponseCB", 
            LAST);
        web_url("GetUnreadNotifications_2", 
            "URL=https://[URL]/api2/notifications/GetUnreadNotifications", 
            "Resource=0", 
            "RecContentType=application/json", 
            "Referer=https://[URL]/", 
            "Snapshot=t14.inf", 
            "Mode=HTML", 
            LAST);
        web_sync("ParamCreated=stopAsync", "RetryIntervalMs=500", "RetryTimeoutMs=120000", LAST);
        web_stop_async("ID=Poll_0",LAST);
```

Loadrunner sees the polling mechanism as Wasted Time, but in reality it's polling untill all data is received and I need to include this in the actual Duration.

**How can I include the web_sync polling part inside Duration instead of Wasted Time?**

```
ended with a "Pass" status (Duration: 33,9532 Wasted Time: 33,3178).
```

*Yes, this API is that slow...*

Answer (score 0):

I believe wasted time is the time to execute the loadrunner API itself.   This came about in the late 1990s because a competing tool laid marketing landmines at customers for the Mercury team for not tracking the time to execute the APIs like their "superior tool" did at the time.

Well, you place a barrier in front of Mercury sales, then engineering gets involved.  And "Boom!" we get tracked wasted time, along with tracked think time.   You could reduce your polling window from 500ms to 750 milliseconds to have less overhead on your polling execution.